# Diagonal Matrices with Zero on Diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As far as I understand, a diagonal matrix is one whose non-zero elements are on the main diagonal. Am I correct in assuming that the diagonal can contain zeros as well? ie:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 0&0 \\ 0&1 \\ \end{bmatrix} $$
and
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&0 \\ \end{bmatrix} $$

are also diagonal matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, you are right, there may be zero elements on the diagonal. But your definition of *diagonal matrix* is slightly ambiguous. A clearer definition (in my opinion) is that **all off-diagonal entries are zero**.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I just wanted to make sure that these are diagonal as well as I need to prove that they are zero divisors.

Comment: @alexcoco No problem. Glad I could help clarify this.